# Github Merge Changes to Master before or after Pull Request

Tags: pandas, github

I've checked out a branch for a `pandas` issue, made changes and commited.

Should I merge my branch into the master branch of my fork of pandas and make a pull request of that, or should I make a pull request from the new branch and let  someone with write privileges merge that branch `into pandas-dev/master`?

Comment: You typically make a PR from a branch, see https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-pull-request: *"These changes are proposed in a branch, which ensures that the `master` branch only contains finished and approved work."*

Comment: If you are forking a repo to diverge from the original and make your own version, then it's ok to merge into master because the "source of truth" is now under your control. If you are forking to contribute then you should always raise the PR from a branch. Control of what goes into the master branch in this case should be left to the owner. After your changes are merged to the master branch of the original repo you can update your fork to have the changes reflected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pull requests were made to be started from branches. The [GitHub docs](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-pull-request) say

> Create a pull request to propose and collaborate on changes to a repository. These changes are proposed in a *branch*, which ensures that the master branch only contains finished and approved work.

---

One way this makes a difference can be seen if you begin pulling commits from the master branch into your master branch, which you are sourcing a pull request from. Because you have a separate commit in the middle of your history (what you're pull requesting), git will not be able to fast-forward, but will instead create a lot of merge commits. When that pull request is merged (if the owners actually allow it), it will contain all the merge-commits that you created in your local repo, which will really clog up the history.

---

All that to say, when you are making changes to a source repository that you are planning to start pull requests for, always do it in a separate branch from your master branch.